# Compiling php_excel and LibXL on Windows

Tags: php, windows, compilation

I'm trying to build PHP on Windows together with a popular C library for Excel manipulation, [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/download.html). This library has a native PHP object-based extension called [php_excel](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel/downloads). I'm attempting to build the latter as a shared DLL on Windows, rather than statically compiling it into PHP for distribution.

My starting point for compilation is the PHP buidling for Windows [wiki entry](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) and I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and the Windows SDK 6.1 as recommended. For the purposes of further paths in this explanation, my reference directory is `c:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\`. References to the PHP snapshot are shown as the folder `php5.3-x` where x is the snapshot build datetime.

After the extraction of the PHP snapshot, I'm adding `bin\libxl.dll`, `include_c\*` and `lib\libxl.lib` to the respective folders in `deps`.

I then extract the php_excel extension into `php5.3-x\ext\excel-0.9.1`.

Running `buildconf` and `configure --help` reveals that the extension is being seen. I'm then running:

```
configure --disable-all --enable-cli --with-excel=shared --disable-zts --disable-isapi --disable-nsapi
nmake
```

To achieve a VC9 non-thread-safe build of the DLL.

On `nmake`, I'm coming up against syntax errors for every header file in LibXL:

```
c:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\deps\include\enum.h(4) : error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'libxl'
c:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\deps\include\enum.h(4) : error C2059: syntax error: ';'
...
```

and syntax errors in the excel.c source for php_excel:

```
ext\excel-0.9.1\excel.c(33) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'f'
ext\excel-0.9.1\excel.c(33) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'f'
ext\excel-0.9.1\excel.c(33) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
ext\excel-0.9.1\excel.c(33) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
...
```

Here, for example, are these two sections from the respective files:

```
enum.h

#ifndef ENUM_CPP_H
#define ENUM_CPP_H

namespace libxl { # line 4
    ...
}

excel.c

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include "libxl.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "php.h"
#include "php_ini.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"
#include "ext/date/php_date.h"
#include "php_excel.h"
#include "zend_exceptions.h"

static long xlFormatBorder(FormatHandle f) # line 33
{
    return 1;
}
```

I don't see syntax errors but assume I am missing an obvious step somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the build and pulled a request to fix the build. See the bins here http://www.php.net/~pierre/

Comment: Many thanks Pierre - any tips on where I am going wrong on the compilation? I'd still like to get these compiling locally and I receive the same errors, even when using the version of php_excel including [your change commits](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel/commit/4aa7a522b8c52d2956a8765f219bdfa3a9ba8ef4) and a new PHP 5.3 snapshot from this morning.

This is for both TS and NTS builds.

Comment: Thanks again Pierre, this now compiles for me with [your latest commit](https://github.com/pierrejoye/php_excel/commit/2e4ceedb792d849475310f45e0f6efc6efff431f)